# discord.py AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, string, discord.py

so the thing is, i'm making a discord bot in python with python.py and i'm making a command to mute someone by put their user id in a json file.

```
@client.command()
async def mute(user):
with open("muted.json", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
if not user.id in data:
    data[user.id] = {}
else:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "The user is already muted")
```

It's saying at "if not user.id in data:" that "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'"
How can I fix that ?

Comment: try using `'user.id'` instead of `user.id` (in both occurences).

Answer (score 2):

By default, all arguments to commands are strings.  If you want the library to convert them for you, you have to tell it what type you want it converted to by supplying a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) with a type annotation.  If you want to reference the `message` that invoked the command, you'll also have to tell the librtary to pass the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) into the command callback.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.User):
    with open("muted.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if not user.id in data:
        data[user.id] = {}
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "The user is already muted")
```

It's worth noting that this command doesn't really do anything.  It creates a dictionary from a file, modifies it, then discards it when the function ends. You should instead have a module-level `data` dictionary that is loaded once, then saved whenever you modify it.