# How to get the User ID of a member in Discord.py when I mention them?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the User ID when I mention them in a command.

I have a command to warn members, and I want to keep track of a member's warnings. So I want their User ID to keep track of the same. But when I try to get a User ID when I mention them, it says `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`.

The code I used to get the User ID is -

```
@commands.command()
async def getID(self, ctx, member):
    ctx.send(member.id)
```

Note that I am using Cogs, that's why I passed in self first.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903121/discord-py-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your definition `(self, ctx, member)` - your bot gets just text from discord and without anything library will think of `member` as a string object and thus it does not have attribute 'id', as your error says. The library's solution to this: type-hinting, if you provide type-hint like this `..., member: discord.Member)` - the library will try to convert provided input into `discord.Member` object, which will have `member.id` as its attribute.
2. `ctx.send` is a coroutine and thus should be awaited

So MRE would look something like this

```py
@commands.command()
async def getID(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member.id)
```